# How can I pass more resource IDs with a single request?

Tags: services, 8

I've been using the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module with the [REST](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest) module from quite some time now.

I want to make a single *PUT application/json* request with an appropriate JSON raw body for it, passing more than a resource ID, instead of making different requests. So far as I read, I found I can use `PUT request: http://.../resource_endpoint/resouce_name/resource_id`.

Comment: You can only do one request at a time. Otherwise, you'll have to implement a custom service resource to handle the batch operation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [`hook_services_resources()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!services.services.api.php/function/hook_services_resources/6).

```php
function example_services_resources() {
  $resources = array();
  $resources['einvoice'] = array(
    'actions' => array(
      'search' => array(
        'access callback' => '_example_resource_access',
        'callback'        => '_example_resource_search',
        'help'            => 'E-invoice online checker.',
        'file'            => array(
          'type'   => 'inc',
          'module' => 'exmaple',
          'name'   => 'resources/exmaple.resource',
        ),
        'args'            => array(
          array(
            'name'        => 'input',
            'optional'    => FALSE,
            'source'      => array('data' => 'input'),
            'type'        => 'string',
            'description' => 'Put the query string to get some data.',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $resources;
}
```

In the *example.resource.inc* file, you put the functions declared  in that hook.

```php
function _example_resource_access() {
  return TRUE;
}

function _example_resource_search($input) {
  // To do something you want.
}
```